# PHP function returning 'null' for success method in jQuery.ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I have an issue very similar to this one: [jquery json function returning null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035401/jquery-json-function-returning-null).

I have followed the above contained advice, however, and am still seeing `null` as a result.

Here is my code:

JS:

```
Gallery.prototype.getImages = function(opt){
  var self = this;
      var baseurl = 'http://local.gallery.dev'
  $.ajax({
    url: baseurl+='/controllers/ajax.php',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: {action : opt},
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function(data){
        //self.setImages(data);
        console.log(data)
    },
    error: function(){
        console.log('NOPE');
    }
  });
}
```

PHP:

```
class ajax_controller {

function __construct(){

    if(isset($_POST['action']) && !empty($_POST['action'])) {
        $action = $_POST['action'];
        switch($action) {
            case 'Newborn' : $this->Newborn();
                break;
        }
    }
}
/*
 * Process Newborn Gallery request.
 */
public function Newborn(){
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode(array(
      'images/gallery/albums/newborn/kylie/thumbnail/kylie-album.jpg',
      'images/gallery/albums/newborn/payton/thumbnail/payton-1-thumbnail.png'
    ));
}
}
```

The console/debugger/network panel are all saying that I am talking to the ajax controller correctly, however, the `data` of the success method only returns null.

I am fairly novice to PHP, any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Thanks, Ken

**UPDATE**

My call is still returning null so I thought i'd paste my headers here.

```
Request URL:http://local.sunnyrose.dev/controllers/ajax.php
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:14
Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8
Host:local.sunnyrose.dev
Origin:http://local.sunnyrose.dev
Referer:http://local.sunnyrose.dev/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML,              

like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.56 Safari/535.11
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Request Payload
action=Newborn
Response Headersview source
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:0
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Mon, 05 Mar 2012 17:49:53 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=92
Server:Apache/2.2.14 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8l PHP/5.3.1 mod_perl/2.0.4       

Perl/v5.10.1
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.3.1
```

Comment: Thanks for all the answers guys, amending my code now. Will update soon.

Answer (score 3):

echo at the end of constructor.i think you doesnt echo anything in controller , so ajax response is null.
whioch framework u use?

Comment: Actually i didnt even catch that. It should still echo though, however it has the potential to cause problems down the line. +1

Comment: If you could provide an example of what you mean I would be uber greatfull. Still kind of confused at the `echo` logic there.

Comment: For getting data from php to ajax to js,you have to echo/print in php file .so it can trasport to js.in __construct just write at end of function echo 'test';

Comment: ohh yeah..i dint see that u call that.i m sorry

Comment: hehe all good, anymore ideas as to why it might still be returning null?

Answer (score 2):

I dont think thats going to produce valid JSON. If you want an actual array with numeric keys then use numeric keys in the PHP array:

```
echo json_encode(array(
  1 => 'images/gallery/albums/newborn/kylie/thumbnail/kylie-album.jpg',
  2 => 'images/gallery/albums/newborn/payton/thumbnail/payton-1-thumbnail.png'
));
```

OR

```
echo json_encode(array(
  'images/gallery/albums/newborn/kylie/thumbnail/kylie-album.jpg',
  'images/gallery/albums/newborn/payton/thumbnail/payton-1-thumbnail.png'
));
```

which will output the following js:

```
[
  'images/gallery/albums/newborn/kylie/thumbnail/kylie-album.jpg',
  'images/gallery/albums/newborn/payton/thumbnail/payton-1-thumbnail.png'
]
```

Comment: In other words remove the single quotes from the `'1' =>` etc, ? I did that, still returning null. Not sure why I had that quotes there in the the first place.

Answer (score 2):

In your /controllers/ajax.php file are you running your functions?

```
class ajax_controller {
    function __construct(){
        if(isset($_POST['action']) && !empty($_POST['action'])) {
            $action = $_POST['action'];
            switch($action) {
                case 'Newborn' : return $this->Newborn();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    /*
     * Process Newborn Gallery request.
     */
    public function Newborn(){
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        return json_encode(array(
          'images/gallery/albums/newborn/kylie/thumbnail/kylie-album.jpg',
          'images/gallery/albums/newborn/payton/thumbnail/payton-1-thumbnail.png'
        ));
    }
}

$controller = new ajax_controller;
echo $controller->__construct();
```

Comment: Great catch! - still returning null, however :(

Answer (score 1):

you are using part of a `url`

```
url: '/controllers/ajax.php',
```

try using your full `url`

like

```
var baseurl = 'http://www.example.com';

url: baseurl+'/controllers/ajax.php',
```

**EDIT**

try changing

```
header('Content-type: application/json')
```

to

```
header('Content-type: text/json');
```

or

```
header('Content-type: text/plain');
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267546/correct-http-header-for-json-file

Comment: Still returning null. I'm developing this locally on my own vhost in apache 'http://local.sitename.dev' could that be causing 'same-origin-policy' issues?

Comment: @ken: not as long aa you are accessing the site with that same domain name.

Answer (score 0):

I finally dug around the headers and realized the problem was that .`ajax()` was sending my PHP script an empty array.

The fix was to get rid of `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8`, and the `header()` function in the PHP script.

It now sends and receives data just fine. (*goes to read up on configuration docs*)

Thanks for all the help - my script would;ve been broken for other reasons w/o many of your answers :)